# What does the old-style JOIN syntax mean in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, outer-join

I need to edit old-styled T-SQL code.

- What does `=*` mean?
- What does `*=` mean?

I think, that they are JOIN, but I don't know, what JOIN type is each of them.

Comment: Those are outer joins

Comment: And what is difference between of them?

Comment: One is a left join the other a right join. See the manual for details https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259187%28v=sql.80%29.aspx#_where_clause

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found answer!

```
-- Example 1: Deprecated syntax for an inner join
SELECT [T2].[c3], [T1].[c3] 
FROM [dbo].[Table2] T2, [dbo].[Table1] T1 
WHERE [T1].[ID] = [T2].[ID]

-- Example 2: Current syntax for an inner join
SELECT [T2].[c3], [T1].[c3] 
FROM [dbo].[Table2] AS T2
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Table1] as T1
ON [T2].[ID] = [T1].[ID]

-- Example 3: Deprecated syntax for a left outer join
SELECT [T2].[c3], [T1].[c3] 
FROM [dbo].[Table2] T2, [dbo].[Table1] T1 
WHERE [T1].[ID] *= [T2].[ID]

-- Example 4: Fixed syntax for a left outer join
SELECT [T2].[c3], [T1].[c3] 
FROM [dbo].[Table2] AS T2
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Table1] as T1
ON [T2].[ID] = [T2].[ID]

-- Example 5: Deprecated syntax for a right outer join
SELECT [T2].[c3], [T1].[c3] 
FROM [dbo].[Table2] T2, [dbo].[Table1] T1 
WHERE [T1].[ID] =* [T2].[ID]

-- Example 6: Fixed syntax for a right outer join
SELECT [T2].[c3], [T1].[c3] 
FROM [dbo].[Table2] AS T2
RIGHT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Table1] as T1
ON [T2].[ID] = [T2].[ID]
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172122(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: There are obvious typos here: `[T2].[ID] = [T2].[ID]`. MSDN is not perfect.